# Groovy FileInputStream.eachByte(4) {buffer -> }

Tags: file, groovy, fileinputstream

I have a problem with method `.each(int bufferSize, Closure closure)`.

```
new FileInputStream(fname).eachByte(4) { buffer ->
    def x = new BigInteger(buffer);
    println x;
}
```

And similar here:

```
new File(fname).eachByte(4) { buffer -> 
    def x = new BigInteger(buffer);
    println x;
}
```

So, i get a

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:  No signature of method:
>   $_readBitSeq_closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: ([B,
>   java.lang.Integer) values: [[60, 110, -13, 95], 4]

Anybody know how to solve this problem???

Thanks, Oleg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eachByte( int )` method [requires a 2 parameter](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#eachByte%28int,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) Closure

The first parameter is the byte buffer, the second parameter is the number of bytes that were read from the Stream.  Try:

```
new FileInputStream(fname).eachByte(4) { buffer, nReads ->
    def x = new BigInteger(buffer);
    println x;
}
```

The same is [true for `File.eachByte( int )`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachByte%28int,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29)